# fminunc is not converging

Tags: matlab, optimization

Im using fminunc to minimize a function with 450 variables, here are the lines

```
 opts = optimset('Display','Iter','MaxIter', 10000000,'MaxFunEvals', 100000000,'TolX', 1e-12,'TolFun', 1e-12);
 [x,fval,exitflag] = fminunc(@function,x0,opts);
```

Note that I dont provide the gradient, so fminunc uses quasi-newton algorithm.
After some iterations it endes with this final message

```
fminunc stopped because it cannot decrease the objective function
along the current search direction.
```

But if I restart the code with the new point obtained, it continued decreasing, so Im not in the minimum.
It seems to me that the algorithm its just looking for the minimum simply along one direccion and when it finds it, it stops instead start searching among the other direccions.

Any clue how to modify the problem so that doesnt happen and find the minimum? or other programm I should use in order to do it faster?

Edit: the function is convex

Comment: I think that fminunc looks for the local minimum instead of the global minimum, if you are looking for the global minimum, you might have to do some convex optimization

Comment: the function is convex, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: if the function is actually convex you likely have some scaling issue. please post the function you are trying to optimize.

Comment: Well, I expect all the 450 variables to have the same order of magnitud so it shouldnt be a scaling problem neither. The function is really complex sometimes its difficult even to me, who have implemented it, to undestand it, so I think it wouldnt be of much use, I just wanted to know if this strange behaviour of fminunc has an "easy" solution.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem can occur if your have numerical noise in your objective function. Then gradient/hessian become noisy and the step is off, and line searching ends with precisely this error.

Try plotting your criterion in an interval around your starting values but change one of the parameters from x0(i) to
linspace(x0(i)*(1-1e07, x(i)*(1+1e07), 100), one number at the time.

If the function looks very jittery, that may be your problem.

Alternatively, maybe you are starting in a region where the function is not convex? In that case try fminsearch to begin with.

Otherwise, consider using analytic gradients.

Also, perhaps your tolerance are set too fine. Try reducing tolfun and tolx to 1e-08. Your problem is very high dimensional.